# How can I safely scale down Elasticsearch cluster on AWS?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch cluster and currently it has 9 instances which include 1 shard and 8 replicas. When I try to scale down the cluster to have 2 instances (1 shard and 1 replica) I got this error: `Error: ValidationException: New cluster configuration has insufficient storage capacity for your current data.`.

I expect it to delete the extra replicas from the cluster. Why doesn't it allow me to do that? Does it try to merge the extra replicas into one? what is the correct way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings won't change because you scaled down your cluster. Since you've specified 1 primary shard and 8 replicas, elasticsearch will try to move those replicas to the other nodes. You need to update your [settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) first (1 primary shard and 1 replica) and then scale down your cluster

```
PUT /INDEX_NAME_HERE/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scaling Down an Elasticsearch Cluster

Elasticsearch must be resilient to the failures of individual nodes. It achieves this resilience by considering cluster-state updates to be successful after a [quorum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/modules-discovery-quorums.html) of nodes have accepted them. A quorum is a carefully-chosen subset of the master-eligible nodes in a cluster.

Quorums must be carefully chosen so the cluster cannot elect two independent masters which make inconsistent decisions, ultimately leading to data loss. to know [more..](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-new-era-for-cluster-coordination-in-elasticsearch)

**Preparations Before scaling down**

- Back up your cluster to have something to restore if things go wrong down the line.
- Check with the master nodes configuration minimum master nodes according to the
- Stop all writes to your cluster as it will not be safe to failover after our downscaling, but not mandatory if all goes fine.
- Make sure that you are not overloading the cluster by making it too small disk space and memory, else cluster will become read only with [Low disk watermark](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html).
- Bring down the index replication factor to 1 in order to save space and speed up shard relocation during scaling, since less shards need to be created and moved around. Also, this saves a lot of space in duplicated data.

  ```
  curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/twitter/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
  {
      "index" : {
         "number_of_replicas" : 1
      }
  }
  '
  ```
- Rebalance the cluster gracefully before you start scaling down.
- Cluster need to be healthy with green status, check with the `shards` and `status`

  Health

  ```
  curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"
  ```

  Expected Output

  ```
  {
    "cluster_name" : "\"es-data-cluster\"",
    "status" : "green",
    "timed_out" : false,
    "number_of_nodes" : 1,
    "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
    "active_primary_shards" : 0,
    "active_shards" : 0,
    "relocating_shards" : 0,
    "initializing_shards" : 0,
    "unassigned_shards" : 0,
    "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
    "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
    "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
    "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
    "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
  }
  ```

  Shards

  ```
  curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/shards"
  ```

  Expected Output

  ```
  twitter 2 p STARTED    0   0b 172.18.0.2 es-node
  twitter 1 p STARTED    0   0b 172.18.0.2 es-node
  twitter 0 p STARTED    0 230b 172.18.0.2 es-node
  ```

When the cluster status is `green` and all shards are `STARTED` then you are good to go with scalling down.

**Steps to scale down**

- Remove one data node — the cluster will go into the yellow state.
  Now observe the

  - logs of the cluster,
  - check with `STARTED`, and `UNASSIGNED` shards

  If the logs say `Marking shards as stale` that means shard which is no more available for assignment and will be removed. Then the elasticsearch inbuild capabilities starts rebalancing the Shards.

  ```
  curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty"
  ```

  This command will provide explanations for shard allocations in the cluster in detail.
- Wait for green—then the cluster has replicated the lost shards.

> The cluster health is `red` so there is at least one unassigned primary shard. You need to focus on an unassigned cluster.